# How to write regex that can accept only numbers or fraction format?

Tags: regex, regular-language

I want to write regex that can only accept numbers or a fraction. For example:

```
12453  Valid
562    Valid
1142/75  Valid
65/1    Valid
1.2    Invalid
asd    Invalid
/45    Invalid
```

Now i wrote this for fraction

```
^\d+\/\d+$
```

It is working fine for 1/1,45/15 etc

This is for numbers only

```
^\d*$
```

Now user can write only numbers or fraction. How i make a regex that can be used in this case?

Comment: Make fraction optional: `^\d+(?:\/\d+)?$`

Comment: Do you really want to also match an empty string? Your `^\d*$` can.

Comment: @anubhava thanks. It's working. Please post it as answer so i can mark it right.

Comment: @Umer, you need `^(?:\d+(?:\/\d+)?)?$` to also match an empty string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now user can write only numbers or fraction. How i make a regex that can be used in this case?

You can make fraction part optional in your regex by grouping in in an optional group.

You can use:

```
^\d+(?:\/\d+)?$
```

`(?:\/\d+)?` is optional non-capturing-group that makes fractional part optional in regex pattern.